# How to save Dictionary<String, Any> to UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a little difficulty saving a dictionary to UserDefaults().

Tried `UserDefaults.standard.set(dict1, forKey: "dict1"`, but getting an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object

Also tried `NSKeyedArchiver` however this error pops up:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This is the dictionary:

```
@State var dict1: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "progress": Double(0.5),
    "count": 10,
    "max": 20,
    "name": "dict1",
    "value": Double(10.00),
    "color": Color.green,
    "completed": false,
    "incrament": Double(1)
]
```

This is Xcode 11 SwiftUI. 
Any help or tips? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's probably because you are trying to store Color.green. Try removing that (for now) and see what happens.

Comment: As Rob mentioned you – definitely – cannot save `Color` because it does not conform to `NSCoding`. And in Swift there are better ways than *objective-c-ish* `NSKeyedArchiver`

Comment: the problem is storing Color.green. You have to convert it to Data then recover it the same way.

Comment: Okay thank you. Just used Hex values for the colours instead - seemed like a simpler workaround!

Answer (score 0):

```
        struct LocalData {
        static var myDicts: [dictionary] {
                get {
                    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: #function) else { return [] }
                    do {
                        let myDict = try JSONDecoder().decode([dictionary].self, from: data)
                        return myDict
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return []
                }
                set{
                    let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: #function)
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                }

        }
    }


struct dictionary: Codable {
    var progress: Double?
    var count: Int?
    var max: Int?
    var name: String?
    var value: Double?
    var color: String?
    var completed: Bool?
    var increment: Double?
    }
```

Usage:

```
var dict: [dictionary] = [dictionary(progress: 10, count: 10, max: 10, name: "mydict", value: 10.5, completed: true, increment: 10.4)]

    LocalData.myDicts = dict
    print(LocalData.myDicts)
```

for color you can do this:

```
if LocalData.myDicts[0].color == red {
 self.view.backgroundColor = .red
}else if LocalData.myDicts[0].color == green {
 self.view.backgroundColor = .green
}
```